# How to locally edit GTK themes like Mojave Dark in Ubuntu where .CSS file has some web link?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Previously, I was able to edit any theme that has some content in the .css file. Mostly it was changing colors and I changed the .css file of gtk3 and it would bring the required change in color to themes. It works fine in all recent Ubuntu editions 20.04, 20.10 as well as 21.04.

Surprisingly I am unable to edit some of the themes. When I open there .css file of Mojave Dark, I get the following types of line:

```
@import url("resource:///org/gnome/Mojave-theme/gtk-dark.css");
```

How can I locally edit such type of .css file where some web address is provided in place of styling content? If there is similar tool like Oomox for Ubuntu to edit gtk themes, it would be easier. Oomox works for other themes like Materia, Numix and Arch but not for GTK.

If someone knowledgeable person knows and can help me, it would be very great.

Comment: That's not a web address. It is a URL, but it isn't located on the web.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tweaking newer GTK3 themes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765909/tweaking-newer-gtk3-themes)

Comment: I will read this answer you spotted know and let you know if it works.

Comment: I read this answer now. The answer tells something about NUMIX themes but this url aspect is not discussed over there on that question or answer. If it is not located on web can we edit on our system itself? Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the answer for your question's immediate scope: https://askubuntu.com/q/1261156/1157519 This will already set you up for some quick tinkering on static CSS files. Then, here is this info for a longer-term mindset (editing Sassy CSS (infused with variables, functions, mixins and more) like it's meant to be and compiling): https://askubuntu.com/a/1313366/1157519

Comment: Maverick: oh, sorry, I meant to link to the same question that @Levente did, but copied the wrong link. The one I actually linked to was only for explanation - it shows how the URL aspect works  - everything goes into a compiled gtk-resource binary file, from where C functions like `gtk_css_provider_load_from_resource` will load particular part needed.

Comment: All right. So it is relating to coding. So I won't be able to edit such type of themes because I do not have coding knowledge. I only changed colors in gtk3.css files previously for other themes by ctrl+f and replace with desired colors and ctrl+s. This did it. For a layman this is rather tough operation. Right.

Comment: There is already a direct well-written answer to this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261156/editing-yaru-gtk-theme-where-is-resource-com-ubuntu-themes-yaru-3-20-gtk-css). I got to know about this myself from reading that answer :)